# Bootstrap - Collapse sidebar programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is collapse sidebar on a click of a button. To achieve this I'd have to know "where" is the event that collapses sidebar automatically and how to trigger it programatically. As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sat9E/3/), if you resize vertical handler to the left, the `Dashboard` menu option will show up, and if you resize it to the right, that little button will show up on the right corner.

**** EDIT ****

Looking at the `css` I could find WHERE the event happens: `@media (min-width:768px) { ... }`, so, when the width of screen is < 768px, the side bar will collapse and the navigation button will show up. How can I achieve this action programmatically? A picture explains the behavior I want:

[image]

Comment: So are you saying you want the functionality of the collapsed nav on the sidebar?

Comment: For example: if my sidebar is not collapsed (as I said on the example above resizing veritcal handler to left), I'd like to click on a button and collapse sidebar, so that I'd have my application with full width

Answer (score 5):

The `Navbar` is built using Bootstrap's [**`.collapse()`**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) function.
You can use any of the following commands:

```js
.collapse('toggle')
.collapse('show')
.collapse('hide')
```

#### With JavaScript:

```html
<button id="ToggleNavScript" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >
    Toggle Nav JavaScript
</button>
```

```js
$("#ToggleNavScript").click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

#### With HTML anywhere else on the page:

```html
<button id="ToggleNavAttr" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
        Toggle Nav Attribute
</button>
```

### [Here's a working demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/k98Bn/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's not exactly what I wanted.. Instead of collapsing `nav bar` I'd like to collapse `side bar`. I guess I'm not being clear here but I want to have something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/dmyTR/36/show/#). When I click on the arrow on the left, the menu should be hidden, the nav button (those 3 little horizontal bars) should show up on right corner and the content of my page should occupy full width of the screen

Comment: @lucasdc, can you come up with a dead simple drawing in MS Paint of different states of the application and what your visual expectations are and upload it to imgur.  I'm having a little bit of a hard time following your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_in&stacked=h) of W3School.

This is main toggle button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="false">Simple collapsible</button>
```

Below is div which you want to toggle:

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
```

So you just to need 'toggle' class to your side bar div. and make sure that it doesn't contain 'in' class which means it is in expand state.