# Collapse Sidebar on Page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Iam working on a C# MVC project. It works perfectly until today i come across a problem.

I added a new view to the project. It works correctly. But i need to collapse the sidebar when the page loads. The sidebar collapse when i click the collapse button. But i need it on page load.

i found [this Question :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531937/bootstrap-collapse-sidebar-programatically) But it didn't help me, as in the answer said i tried adding javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebartoggler').collapse('toggle');
})
```

but i come across an error `Uncaught Error: Collapse is transitioning`.

Here is my layout header code :

```
<header class="topbar">
        <nav class="navbar top-navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light">
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Logo -->
            ....// code
            <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- toggle and nav items -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-md-0">
                    <!-- This is  -->
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link nav-toggler hidden-md-up text-muted waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i></a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link sidebartoggler hidden-sm-down text-muted waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" id="sidebartoggler"><i class="ti-menu"></i></a> </li>
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- Search -->
                    ....// code
                    <!-- Messages -->
                    ....// code

                </ul>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- User profile and search -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav my-lg-0">
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- Comment -->
                    ....// code
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- Messages -->                        
                    ....// code
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->

                    <!-- Language -->
                    ....// code
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

What i need in page load is something like :

[image]

**UPDATE**

My sidebar code

```
    <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <div class="scroll-sidebar">
            <div class="user-profile">
                <div class="profile-text">


                    <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInY">
                        <a href="~/Company/Index" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-user"></i> Company</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-user"></i> My Profile</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-wallet"></i> My Balance</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-email"></i> Inbox</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ti-settings"></i> Account Setting</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> <a href="~/Account/Logout" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul id="sidebarnav">
                    <li><a href="~/Company/_CompanyDetails"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Company</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-gauge"></i><span class="hide-menu">Admin Tables </span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="~/Countries/Index">Countries</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/State/Index">State</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Tax/Index">Tax</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Role/Index">Roles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Branch/Index">Branches</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-group"></i><span class="hide-menu">Contacts</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="~/Customer/Index">Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Customer/ProspectFollowup">Prospect Followup</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i><span class="hide-menu">Item</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="~/Item/Index">Items</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/ItemCategories/Index">Item Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/ItemBrand/Index">Item Brands</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/ItemManufacture/Index">Item Manufacturer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Warehouse/Index">Warehouse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="hide-menu">Purchase Order</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="~/Purchase/Index"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Purchase Order</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="~/Bill/Index"><i class="fa fa-credit-card "></i>Bill</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="~/SalesOrder/Index"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>Sales Order</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><span class="hide-menu">Users</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="~/User/Index">Users</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid"></i><span class="hide-menu">Other</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="~/PermissionFunction/Index">Permission Function</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/PaymentMode/Index">Payment Mode</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/DocNoFormat/Index">Document Format</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Unit/Index">Unit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="~/Report/Index"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Sidebar navigation -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Sidebar scroll-->
        <!-- Bottom points-->
        <div class="sidebar-footer">

            <a href="#" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Settings"><i class="ti-settings"></i></a>

            <a href="#" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email"><i class="mdi mdi-gmail"></i></a>

            <a href="~/Account/Logout" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout"><i class="mdi mdi-power"></i></a>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the markup of the sidebar as well.

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: If you're using the [collapse plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/), the element normally needs the `collapse` class. This "hides" the element, and then the toggle method adds the `in` class, which then "shows" the element. Have you tried that?

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: That's what the docs are for (I specifically linked to the collapse documentation). Try reviewing them. You might also find this useful: http://blog.codeply.com/2016/05/18/bootstrap-sidebar-responsive-examples/

Comment: can you inspect your site in browser, if there is any other class being added to the div with class left-sidebar, when you collapse the side bar using that button?

Answer (score 1):

So, if clicking works on your sidebartoggler button, you can simply click it using code.

like here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebartoggler').click();
});
```

Comment: okay. just to make sure the click code works, try running it from the browser console after the page loads.

Comment: otherwise, you can also check your side bar code to see if there is any css class that marks it as collapsed or expanded. Can you share the side bar code?

Answer (score 1):

Add **toggled** along with the Navbar class

```
<nav class="toggled navbar navbar-dark.....
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you put `.` selector for `sidebartoggler`, it should be `#` since it is an `id` selector not a `class` selector;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#sidebartoggler').collapse('toggle');
})
```

[More Info](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

add collapse class

Answer (score 0):

You can use "data-toggle" and "data-target" properties of the bootstrap to achieve this functionality.

This is main toggle button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="false">Simple collapsible</button>
```

Below is div which you want to toggle:

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
```

So you just to need add 'toggle' class to your side bar div. and make sure that it doesn't contain 'in' class which means it is in expand state.